# Javascript Not Firing after Dir Reorganization

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Ok, so here's the situation.
I'm working on a site that allows people to upload things to a database that are then pulled to the frontpage so people can see them.  It is a pretty straightforward site and I had it working real well but i was developing everything at ../html/backend for the sake of simplicity and to make sure nothing was spidered before it was ready to go live.

So once i finished i changed the dir structure to have everything in the /html root, except for the form that allows people to enter info, which i kept at /backend.

this is where i hit the problem, the form is obviously in html and it collects the info, then i have a jquery java script fire on button press that does an ajax PUT to a php file that does the actual INSERT. (don't worry i also do validation in the php file)
but ever since the move the script does not fire.

yes i changed the paths to the scripts and to the jquery file and i can confirm the scripts are being loaded correctly.

i have been struggling with this for days and im sure its something stupid that im overlooking...any ideas?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Firebug or other debugger to find the problem.

Comment: that's definitely the first thing to try.  unfortunately, i've found that sometimes a bug in your JS code interferes with FireBug itself, making it less reliable. especially when something mysteriously stops working, your debugging might stop working too.

Comment: i used firebug at the very beginning and the script is loading, i can view it in FB and it's there...i just have no idea why it isn't firing...maddening!!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm a complete and utter idiot.
I changed the header file that was loading my jquery root and moved it underneath the other scripts that rely on jquery.  moved my jquery rel to the top and hey presto we're back in business.

FML